# SQL Query but reverse WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

I Have an SQL query that works perfectly using wildcard:

```
select * from answer_table where pattern like '%$pattern%'
```

When I enter `Hello` I get all answers from answer_table having that pattern.

What I want to do is the reverse. The user input is a long string e.g. `Hello, are you there?`. My query should check the entire answer_table pattern field if one or more of the patterns is found in the input string.

Sample data in answer_table:

| answer | pattern |
| --- | --- |
| Hello there! | hello |
| What does the fox say? | ding |
| I am sleepy | zz |

For `Hello, are you there?` the query should return `Hello there!`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: ```SELECT answer FROM Answer_Table WHERE LOCATE(Answer_Table.pattern, @entered_value)```

Answer (score 2):

Just swap so that you match the user input with column instead of column with user input:

```
SELECT *
FROM Answer_Table
WHERE 'Hello, are you there?' LIKE CONCAT('%', pattern, '%')
```

Comment: Hmmm.. I never thought that it was possible.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you please accept the answer if it worked?

Comment: Just tried it today. Yes, it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot!